# How to prevent user to input illegal text in QComboBox's lineedit?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I need a widget from `QComboBox`, user can select item from popup or input directly in the linedit, but how to prevent the inputs out of range of the items in QComboBox? or can the text input in the lineedit always be legal?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the `QComboBox::setValidator(const QValidator*)` member function:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#setValidator

This allows you to set a validator to constrain any input that users type into the line edit of the combo box.

Qt provides three validators: `QIntValidator` to constrain inputs to integers within a certain range; `QDoubleValidator` to constrain inputs to floating point values within a certain range and with a specified precision; and `QRegExpValidator` to constrain inputs to a particular regular expression.  If your validation needs are more complex, you may also subclass `QValidator` and write your own and then install it into the combo box.  See also: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I want!